# how to return a json array of a single object as an array using jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jakarta-ee, jackson

I have create the ObjectMapper and also added the package name in the web.xml but still not treating a single object as an array

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperProvider() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you use the `ObjectMapper` and also post what your input looks like?

Comment: Where you do something like `mapper.writeValue();`? Please show this part of your code.